# Turn off google map's infowindow.open(map) asynchronous behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, asynchronous

I have a google maps application, and clicking on a region on the map creates the infowindow.

Here is the structure of my code:

```
...
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(MapArea, "click", showTB);


function showTB () {
    ...
    contentElement = //complicated table with buttons etc

    infowindow.setContent(sContentString);
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);

    //contentElement dom element manipulations, such as:
    $("#table_row").css({background: "#8af"});
}
```

The problem here is that the dom element manipulations at the end usually don't execute. My guess is that `infowindow.open(map)` is asynchronous, and that it usually only finishes executing after the dom element manipulation section, which don't execute since the the html elements don't exist yet.
Placing an alert statement after `infowindow.open(map)` causes the last section of code to usually execute, assumingly due to the delay caused.

So how can I make sure that any code only executes AFTER `infowindow.open()` has finished executing?
Can I make it synchronous?
Is there another way to do this?  I don't just want to add a delay function, since that would be either very slow or unreliable.

Comment: wait for the 'domready' event on the [infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wait for the 'domready' event on the [infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)

> **domready** | None | This event is fired when the  containing the InfoWindow's content 
>   is attached to the DOM. You may wish to monitor this event if you are building out your 
>   info window content dynamically.

code:

```
infowindow.setContent(sContentString);
infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
infowindow.open(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'domready', function() {
  //contentElement dom element manipulations, such as:
  $("#table_row").css({background: "#8af"});
});
```